# Failure to find Class - Spring 3, Hibernate 3, JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

It appears that my class is not found by the JPA infrstructure. Im guessing Spring just cant find it? I have tried package scanning and adding the class to persistence.xml. Anyone out there have any thoughts on what else I can try to allow my select to find that class (and the underlying table)?
thanks!

Here is the code.

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="myApp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:joss/datasources/myDB</jta-data-source>
  <!-- get a special error with this in - see below -->
  <!-- <class>com.src.dao.User</class> -->

  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
  <properties>
     <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class,hbm" />
```

UserDAO Code that causes error:

```
final String queryString="select model from " +User.class.getSimpleName() + " model where model."propertyName+"=:propertyValue";
return getJpaTemplate().executeFind(new JpaCallback() {
   @Override
   public Object doInJpa(EntityManager em) throws PersistenceException {
      //this line causes the error below
      Query query = em.createQuery(queryString);
```

Error Thrown:

```
 201-06-10 18:59:32,736 ERROR [UserDAO] find by property name failed
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped [select model from User model where model.value= :propertyValue]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:User is not mapped [select model from User model where model.value= :propertyValue]
   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:286)
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.src.dao" />
```

also tried it within a bean

```
<beans:bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" packagesToScan="com.src.dao">
   <beans:property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myApp" />
   <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.src.dao" />
</beans:bean>
```

User Class:

```
package com.src.dao

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
* User Entity
*
* @author MyEclipse Persistence Tools
*/
@Entity
@Table (name="USERS", schema="myDb")
public class User extends AbstractUser implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<User> {
```

Adding class to persistence.xml:

```
When I add in <class> to my persistence.xml I get the following on app deploy. The war never deploys:

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/configs/spring/stu-hibernate.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myApp] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
   at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutoWiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
```

Comment: Post a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. It appears that based on my Spring version (3.0.5) I really needed to add the class in persistence.xml. However, my above error would not allow that. Turns out... I needed to add ALL the classes in that package to persistence.xml (minus the DAO's). Once I did that the app started up and worked!
Not sure why all of them were needed.